# How to start app from specific TabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a NavigationController for registration, after that I'm switching on another NavigationController with main logic. Here is my code for switshing:

```
    NSString *containerName = @"MainContainer";
    UINavigationController *root = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:containerName];

    UIWindow *wnd = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    wnd.rootViewController = root;
    [wnd makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But now I need to change NavigationController to TabbarController.
How to switch on tabbar?

**edit**

Before:

UINavigationController (for registration)

if (registration == success) switch for main logic NavigationController

Need:

UINavigationController (for registration)

if (registration == success) switch for TabbarController with (UINavigationController1, UINavigationControlle2)

Comment: What do you mean by changing NavigationController to TabbarController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UITabBarController setViewControllers` function, the parameter is a NSArray.

```
NSString *containerName = @"tabBar";
UITabBarController *root = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:containerName];

UIWindow *wnd = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
wnd.rootViewController = root;
[wnd makeKeyAndVisible];
```

After successfully registration, switch to the tabBarController which has an identifier "tabBar".

Comment: No. Look, I'm on UINavigationControler with storyboardId ("Reg"), after registration I'm going to another Navigation controller, with code in my question. Now I need to go on tabbarcontroller instead of navigationcontroller

Comment: You can set the tabBarController as the rootViewController of the Reg UINavigationController.